# For which parameters is the logistic map chaotic?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

The logistic map is $f_\lambda(x)=\lambda x (1-x)$. It is known that the map is chaotic for $\lambda=4$ (on $[0;1]$) and also for $\lambda>0$ (on some hyperbolic subset of $[0,1]$). My question is:

> For which parameters $\lambda \in (3,4)$ is the logistic map $f_\lambda$ chaotic?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple answer to that. There are infinitely many "windows" where it's not chaotic, infinitely many bands where it is, and a very intricate interplay between the two. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map will get you started.

Comment: The set of parameters for which it is chaotic is very complicated. The key word is "Mandelbrot set".